# Need to align UIDs between 2 books (2 diff languages)

Tags: python-3.x

I work with translations, and the translated version UID must match the original version in English.

Each section (chapter, subsection, etc) has a Unique ID number in English, and they must match to the translated version. If both versions are aligned, it gets ingested easily in our CMS. I have a vague idea on how to start, but am sure this is not a unique problem, and that other folks here may have gone through something similar. The language used for the CMS is XML. If there are UIDs that show up in one language but not the other, it needs to be identified and spat out on a csv file. thanks!

This is new for me, I just finished a Python course and could use some help.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you've written so far, even if it is not yet working properly.

Comment: There are many examples here on Stack Overflow of how to parse XML using Python.

Comment: I have just finished the course so my code is not good yet

Comment: Double the text element like <title uid=1234 lang=de>neues Buch</title> and < title uid=1234 lang=en>new book</title>.